# Set correct dialog location without knowing parent component

Tags: java, user-interface, modal-dialog, parent

I am trying to figure out how to get rid of parents passed in application just for the reason to center dialogs over window or frame.

Application I am responsible for is quite large and not written nicely. Refactoring is in process however it's not easy to decouple some things. Part I am trying to change now is window with tabbed pane. Tabs are same class and consists of several panels which are responsible for different things, so they are also in different packages and classes. Good thing that each class is responsible for single thing only now, bad one is that there are lots of dialog (error, info, question...) which require parent to be centered correctly over window.
I would like not to use these parents all the way down, however at this moment it seems impossible to move all dialogs up in hierarchy. Just setting parent null also doesn't solve problem as they appears somewhere else then window (may be problem on dual screen).

I was thinking about static method in main window which returns current location (or null if doesn't exist). Then set all references to parent as null and set modality type to application. Finaly setLocation on point given by static method. I feel it's not the best solution, but I think it's much better then passing whole window as parameter cca 10 levels down.

What do you think about it? Is it acceptable or do you have some better idea how to handle parent in large GUI application?

EDIT: To specify my intention more deeply - I need dialog boxes to be centered over it's parent. In other words, it doesn't need to be centered on the screen, it should be located directly over the window (not necessarily in the center of window bot just over it). If I set parent to null or location to center of the screen, it can happen that dialog box will display somewhere else than parent window.

EDIT2: So I did it for now as I suggest above. I have created static field JFrame parent = null. Next static method was created `public static Point getCenterPosition(Dimension dimension)`. If something calls this method and parent doesn't exist yet, topleft of the screen is returned (however it can't happen).
As parameter is passed size of dialog I want to center, which is used for inner calculation. As a result method return point, so I can use `dialog.setLocation(ParentFrame.getCenterPosition(dialog.getSize()));`
Now I have dialog nicely centered and I don't need passed parent at all. It's not very nice solution, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

While I am not entirely sure what specific effect you are trying to create without some form of illustration I believe you are trying to get a dialog or pane centered in the screen.

Common practice for the creation of GUI is to base your sizes on the screen resolution that is being used. (this helps your application scale to different resolution monitors)
If you know the screen resolution it is also relatively easy to determine the center point of the screen where you want to display your dialog or pane.

An out of the box solution for determining screen size can be found in the [Toolkit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) (Java7)

I propose you use getScreenSize() or getScreenResolution() (depending on your preferred approach) and then take half of each dimension to find the center point of the screen.

subtract half of your dialog or pane size and you will know the origin point for your pane.

Comment: I added edit comment to be more clear what i need. Just briefly here: I want to locate dialog over window, not center on the screen. But thanks anyway for your comment.

Comment: Just to be clear, do you want it centered over it's direct parent or an arbitrary other level of parent? EDIT: or do you wanted centered over the 'main' window? (I'm guessing the application frame itself?)

Comment: Let's say main window. Actually this window doesn't open other windows or frames, just dialogs for inputs etc. So yes, there will be just one parent for whole application.

Comment: If you look at the [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) there are ancestor methods that enable you to call any level parent, you could use these to find your frame instead of passing it along in the constructors.

Comment: I tried it but because these parts of code are in different classes not extending any gui parts, it returns null.

Comment: Could you please share the general structure of your project (the relevant bits)? Without any knowledge on the structure of the classes I am unsure on how to help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You could put inside of the dialog which has to be centered something like

```
Window ancestor = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(this);
setLocationRelativeTo(ancestor);
```

I use it all the time and it avoids having to pass the parent explicitly.
Of course the dialog has to be called by the parent you want to center to.